# Is it rude to say 'You're actually cute for a person'?

Tags: politeness

> You're actually cute for a person

[elitedaily](https://www.elitedaily.com/life/insulting-question-comments/1271996) says it is rude to say so.

Well, I never heard someone say it.

When someone says that you are pretty, or that you are cute, is it rude or is it a compliment?

Comment: Oh also i want to know whether it is rude to say "Are you sick"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for opinion as to the ethical nature of using a particular expression.

Comment: It can be rude or a compliment. It all depends on the context.

Comment: It's a nonsensical comment, and could be taken several different ways, depending on tone of voice, context, and whether the speaker is a walrus.

Comment: No, the article says that it's rude to say "You're actually cute for a (insert race here) person". Just think of a race and fill in the blank: white, black, Asian, etc.

Comment: Hi Daniel, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We generally prefer if you ask one distinct question at a time. The question may be closed as "too broad" if you ask two questions at once, especially if they are unrelated. Would you please remove the "are you sick" portion, and devise another question based upon that, or at least try to relate it to the rest of the question? It seems like an irrelevant addition as things presently stand.

Comment: As already noted, *for* is the culprit -- it **does** make the sentence politically incorrect.

Comment: @Tuffy It's okay. Sometimes (quite often) certain grammatical constructions make or break the spirit of an uttering. The choice of words or grammatical structure does influence the tone and the semantics. This question involves, the English language, linguistics, pragmatics, etiquette, and so on.

Comment: @Laurel Never mind, it's still inappropriate.

Comment: @Daniel Note this explanation on the same page: "In a matter of a sentence, you managed to completely dissect a person based on what race he or she is, and to top it off, you generalized a group of people on your way to the insult lane."

Comment: The linked page clarifies and explains everything perfectly. -1

Comment: Also, 'actually' often starts an explanation of something unexpected, so the implication is that what is to follow is contrary to the usual situation.

Answer (score 3):

You misread the article. It does not actually state "for a person". It states "for an **(enter race here)** person." So in other words, the article criticizing statements like "You're rather cute, for a black person." for example.

I suppose it does not make too much of a difference since **for** is really the key word. It is being used in this sense, as defined by *[An American Dictionary of the English Language](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/for)* by Noah Webster:

> 27. In proportion to; or rather, looking towards, regarding. He is tall for one of his years, or tall for his age.

Cute could be replaced with any number of complimentary adjectives, and the idea here is that you are not just complimenting a person, but making a relative assessment against other members of that kind. There is otherwise no reason to continue the sentence beyond the adjectival compliment with the prepositional phrase.

Because it is a relative assessment, that does not mean the person is being assessed as possessing that quality in an absolute sense of the word. It just means the people so complimented possess enough of that quality to be an exceptional example of that kind by way of comparison. Because that person is an exceptional example, it implies that you think that it is unusual for people of that kind to possess the ascribed quality.

If someone think a certain kind of person is ugly, it is not necessarily a compliment for that person to suggest that somebody else, who is of that kind, looks prettier than the rest of that kind. That does not necessarily mean that person is actually pretty, even if you use actually as an intensifier.

Such people are not *automatically disqualified* as looking pretty, but they could also be rather average looking, or even just slightly less ugly than the rest of their sort, and considering that you probably have a low opinion of the rest of those people, it is more likely to be interpreted as one of the latter two options than the first.

Consider the following examples, wherein pejorative terms make the actual mechanisms of such a sentence more clear by demonstrating how using a low standard as the basis of comparison can fail to be complimentary:

> He hugged her and kissed her head. You're cute, for a squirt.<sup>[1]</sup>

In this case, squirt is pejorative slang which is meant to insult people, and especially children or younger siblings, for their scrawniness.

> You're cute for a guy who hasn't changed his clothes in two weeks.<sup>[2]</sup>

Most people think people who are not well groomed and do not take care of their clothes look less attractive than they could.

This might not be so insulting is if you are making a neutral comparison, or giving a compliment in comparison to a kind that is known for possessing a certain quality in a way that sets a high standard as the basis of comparison.  You're actually cute, for a girl* can suggest exceptionally high cuteness for instance. However, it can still be taken the wrong way.

These cases are the exception more so than the rule, and in the case of racial comparison, you have to consider that there are long standing traditions of racism that depict members of other races as being inferior to your own kind, so the exact form described by the article also has connotations of racism.

So yes, this is *usually* considered a veiled insult to compliment somebody like that. If you really want to compliment somebody, there is generally no need to qualify that statement with additional stipulations that serve as limitations. Just say "You are [quite] cute." and you should get the compliment across without insinuating anything beyond that.

Something else to take note of is that if you insert an insult instead of a compliment, then all you achieve is making that person feel especially ugly, rather than reversing all of the unsavory implications.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Echoes of the Heart Anthology: An Anthology of Second Chances](https://books.google.com/books?id=MZ52DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT210&pg=PT210#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Jean C. Joachim

<sup>2</sup> [42 Things to Do When You're the Last Guy on Earth by Jackson M. Slade](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z9BbDy8KrVMC&pg=PA189&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3-76tzZngAhXuHjQIHQJ1BJIQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 189

Comment: Please see my comment at OP.